# How to setup Token Based Authentication in NotificationHub for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, azure, apple-push-notifications, azure-notificationhub

My goal is to setup Token Authentication Mode in Azure NotificationHub without using certificate on iOS. I generated the token as it is [described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-http2-token-authentification). Then I put the Token, Key ID, Bundle ID and Team ID into NotificationHub Apple(APNS) section (I am pretty sure that this is working, because I tried to change token to different value and there was an error: "Error updating notification hub". This means that all values were saved properly.

In my mobile app I followed this [tutorial here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/xamarin-notification-hubs-ios-push-notification-apns-get-started) If I try to register user to NotificationHub I have this error:

```
Foundation.NSErrorException: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "(null)" 
UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://dev...NotificationHub/Registrations/?
$filter=deviceToken+eq+''&api-version=2013-04, NSUnderlyingError=0x2811b89c0 
{Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1012 "(null)" 
UserInfo={_kCFURLErrorAuthFailedResponseKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x281903cc0> 
{ URL: https://dev...hubnamespace.servicebus.windows.net/dev...NotificationHub/Registrations/?
$filter=deviceToken+eq+''&api-version=2013-04 } { Status Code: 401, Headers {
    "Content-Length" =     (
        0
    );
    Date =     (
        "Wed, 25 Mar 2020 11:51:09 GMT"
    );
    Server =     (
        "Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0"
    );
    "Strict-Transport-Security" =     (
        "max-age=2592000"
    );
```

This means that there is an issue with authentication. Before this I had different testing solution with another NotificationHub. What I did differently that I created certificate in apple.developer.com and used Certificate Authentication Method and then I switched to Token Authentication Method. In this sample testing project everything worked without any issue. In my current project I didn't create certificate for APNS.

My question is if I need to create certificate even if I want to use Token? If so what is the point of creating token if I have to create certificate too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I would like to thank to Kyle Kamperschroer for helping me out.

To answer my question - you don't need to create certificate if you are using Token Based Authentication.

My connection string and azure hub name were correct. My issue was that RegisteredForRemoteNotifications method in AppDelegate wasn't called. Then the token was empty and it caused authentication issue in NotificationHub.

I solved this in developer.apple.com. I edited provisioning profile and select proper certificates.
[image]

There is also one thing which might probably fixed it. In Identifier section I checked PushNotifications and went through configuration without choosing certificate.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the issues you are encountering.

You are correct - if the Portal let you save the credentials then you have it set up correctly. Notification Hub actually authenticates with APNS on save to verify.

Receiving an authentication error when registering a device indicates there was an authentication issue between your iOS application and Notification Hub itself. There would not have been a corresponding call from the Notification Hubs SDK to APNS itself to get that rejection. I would recommend double checking how you are authenticating with your hub, as it should require both the `Listen` Access Policy/Connection string and the hub name in order to authenticate and register successfully.

This graphic from the Notification Hub docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-registration-management#registration-management-from-the-device) shows what I mean by this:
[image: Registration from device]